# How to make a soft body stay static and not vacillate at all?

Tags: physics, soft-body

I was trying to create a soft body effect.So,I added a cube and gave it a soft body and a sphere(gave it some collision) and animated it.However my cube seems to vacillate(even though the effect is very minimal),which isn't what I want at all.I want it to just stay static at a point.So,how do I do this.Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:BTW Turning the Goal Strengths Default all the way to 1 does make the cube not move but then there will be no deformation of the soft body.

[image]

I also do not want the sphere to actually physically enter so much(as one might expect) into the cube.But I am thinking a fresh new question would be better for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First method:

Simplest solution would be to reduce **Cube** mass to something like 0.5. This will prevent wobbling but it will keep Cube in place so **Sphere** will go trough it.

[image: 1]

Also you will have limited control over **Cube** behavior.

### Second method:

This is what I can recommend. In this method we need to first settle down **Cube** on **Collision Plane**, and then affect it by **Sphere**.

In this method you have full control over collisions. In my example I've used settings that will allow to move **Cube** by **Sphere**, but you can also change it to destroy **Cube** without moving it or just "melt" into it.

[image: 2]

First of all you will need simple **Plane** with **Collision** turned on and **Soft Body and Cloth > Outer > 0.001**

Then set **Cube Soft Body** values as below:

[image: 3]

**Pull** - lower value, lower impact over whole Cube.

**Bending** - higher value will move Cube, lower will keep it in place.

### Test Blend file:

[image]

Comment: Awesome man.Thanks :) I was looking for something exactly like the second one.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Play with Pull and Bending, maybe you will get even better result.

Comment: Yeah man I'm doing.There still seem to be some wobbling.I wonder if we can minimize it to the extent where it isn't distinctly visible if not completely absent.Your second example is the closest I found but still the cube fall very slightly right.Anyway thanks man :)

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker check test blend file in my edit.

Comment: Owh yeah that's the stuff man,perfect :)